# Returning XML node text as an array using find()

Tags: jquery, arrays, xml

I'm trying to figure out how to return a subset of the results of .find() as an array. I have an XML document like this (this is an exercpt from [here](http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=pubmed&retmode=xml&id=20511234)):

```
<MeshHeadingList>
    <MeshHeading>
        <DescriptorName MajorTopicYN="N" UI="D020816">Amino Acid Motifs</DescriptorName>
    </MeshHeading>
    <MeshHeading>
        <DescriptorName MajorTopicYN="N" UI="D020134">Catalytic Domain</DescriptorName>
    </MeshHeading>
    <MeshHeading>
        <DescriptorName MajorTopicYN="N" UI="D003017">Clostridium tetani</DescriptorName>
        <QualifierName MajorTopicYN="N" UI="Q000201">enzymology</QualifierName>
    </MeshHeading>
    <MeshHeading>
        <DescriptorName MajorTopicYN="N" UI="D019281">Dimerization</DescriptorName>
    </MeshHeading>
    <MeshHeading>
        <DescriptorName MajorTopicYN="N" UI="D004926">Escherichia coli</DescriptorName>
        <QualifierName MajorTopicYN="N" UI="Q000201">enzymology</QualifierName>
    </MeshHeading>
</MeshHeadingList>
```

What I want is an array of all of the inner text of the `DescriptorName` elements:

```
{"Amino acid motifs", "catalytic domain", "Clostridium tetani", "Dimerization", "Escherichia coli"}
```

Assuming that `data` is the XML returned by `$.ajax()` for the above URL, this code:

```
$xml = $(data);
var descriptors = $xml.find("DescriptorName");
console.log(descriptors);
```

logs

```
Amino acid motifscatalytic domainClostridium tetaniDimerisationEscherichia coli
```

Meanwhile, iterating through `descriptors` and trying `console.log(descriptors[i].text());` indicates that `descriptors[i].text is not a function`. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create an array from the properties of selected elements you can use `map()`:

```js
var descriptors = $xml.find("DescriptorName").map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();
console.log(descriptors); // = [ "Amino Acid Motifs", "Catalytic Domain", ... ]
```

> Meanwhile, iterating through descriptors and trying `console.log(descriptors[i].text());` indicates that `descriptors[i].text` is not a function. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

This is because when you access a jQuery object (in your `descriptors` variable) using bracket notation you are retrieving the underlying DOMElement. This does not have the `text()` method hence the error. Instead you could use jQuery's `eq()` method:

```
descriptors.eq(i).text();
```

Comment: So iterating through and using `eq()` would yield the same result but evidently in a less efficient way?

Comment: That's it exactly.